# pandas dataframe has all data columns into one column into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load some data into a pandas DataFrame but the .txt file is a little weird.  It has quotes around the first couple headers but not the rest, and when I read it into the pandas data-frame it puts all the data and column names into the first column seperated by "\t" which I believe means a tab in python but why inst it reading it like that

Here is a couple lines of the data copied from a .txt file

```
"Notes" "Cancer Sites"  "Cancer Sites Code" Mortality-Incidence Age-Adjusted Rate Ratio Death Counts    Mortality Population    Mortality Age-Adjusted Rate Incidence Counts    Incidence Population    Incidence Age-Adjusted Rate
    "All Cancer Sites Combined" "0" 0.385   176256  96127579    181.476 469603  96127579    470.919
    "Oral Cavity and Pharynx"   "20010-20100"   0.242   2521    96127579    2.527   10717   96127579    10.437
    "Lip"   "20010" 0.046   16  96127579    0.016   352 96127579    0.358
```

Here is my code so far (FYI it does same thing whether I use headers or not)

```
df = pd.read_fwf("United States and Puerto Rico Cancer Statistics.txt", headers = None)
```

and when I print the `df` I get this as the header...

```
"Notes" "Cancer Sites"  "Cancer Sites Code" Mortality-Incidence Age-Adjusted Rate Ratio Death Counts    Mortality   Population  Mortality   Age-Adjusted    Rate    Incidence   Counts  Incidence.1 Population.1    Incidence.2 Age-Adjusted.1  Rate.1
```

and this as the first two rows of data when I plot the `df`

```
0   "All Cancer Sites Combined"\t"0"\t0.385\t17625...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   "Oral Cavity and Pharynx"\t"20010-20100"\t0.24...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Try using `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')`

Comment: Including sep='\t' alone is not sufficient. I think this case requires a custom delimiter, that allows for the splitting of the elements into the appropriate columns. I am trying to find a solution. If you have control over how the data is written to the txt, you should probably consider to make adjustments. For example, write your data elements comma separated, where each instance is written to one line.

Comment: try reading it into excel and do the formatting there. Once it looks ok save it as a csv and read using pd.read_csv.

Comment: Another option is to reformat your data using regular expressions. This is cumbersome though, and probably not a solution you would like if you are reading a big file. So I would suggest you to stick with @TylerK advice.